# R how to squish a data frame so there aren't holes throughout

Tags: r

Here is my data frame.

```
structure(list(INVOICE_DATE = structure(c(19205, 19205, 19205, 
19206, 19206, 19206, 19207, 19207, 19207), class = "Date"), CATEGORY = c("Accessory", 
"Concentrate", "Edible", "Accessory", "Concentrate", "Edible", 
"Accessory", "Concentrate", "Edible"), Crumble = c(NA, 47, NA, 
NA, 65, NA, NA, 85, NA), Tincture = c(NA, NA, 567, NA, NA, 1028, 
NA, NA, 830), Other = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Battery = c(1079, 
NA, NA, 1027, NA, NA, 1148, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

I can't find the right verb or set of verbs to do this in R.

How can I remove 'NA' values here in a way the squishes the data frame into a nicely formatted table? The `CATEGORY` column could be deleted. Then all the rest of the columns should fit on one row without any holes.

I can't do `df %>% na.omit()` because I end up with a data frame with no observations. The same goes if I try this kind of treatment: `filter(is.na())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

select(df, -CATEGORY) %>%
  pivot_longer(-INVOICE_DATE) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider()

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  INVOICE_DATE Battery Crumble Tincture
  <date>         <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2022-08-01      1079      47      567
2 2022-08-02      1027      65     1028
3 2022-08-03      1148      85      830
```

Comment: thanks very interesting to see going to pivot_longer for the filter and then back to pivot_wider

Comment: I think my issue is really a different issue, though. this answered the question, but I get going back and forth from wide to long. the real issue is that everytime I end up in a wide dataframe the cells are <dbl [1]> instead of a number - on the big dataset I mean

Comment: @hachiko, those sound like list columns, which can happen if each row isn’t uniquely identified. My guess is that your actual data includes cases with more than one non-`NA` value per column per date.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a solution using a grouped `summarize()`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(INVOICE_DATE) %>%
  summarize(across(
    Crumble:Battery, 
    ~ ifelse(sum(!is.na(.x)) > 0, .x[!is.na(.x)], NA)
  ))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  INVOICE_DATE Crumble Tincture Other Battery
  <date>         <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl>
1 2022-08-01        47      567 NA       1079
2 2022-08-02        65     1028 NA       1027
3 2022-08-03        85      830 NA       1148
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `colSums` `by` INVOICE_DATE.

```
by(df[-2], df$INVOICE_DATE, \(x) 
   data.frame(INVOICE_DATE=x[1, 1], t(colSums(x[2:5], na.rm=TRUE)))) |>
  do.call(what=rbind)
#            INVOICE_DATE Crumble Tincture Other Battery
# 2022-08-01   2022-08-01      47      567     0    1079
# 2022-08-02   2022-08-02      65     1028     0    1027
# 2022-08-03   2022-08-03      85      830     0    1148
```